# How to replace the value from checkbox into select option

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a "addCategory" modal and in my modal, I have many list of categories with checkbox..
[image: AddCategory modal]

When I check the categories, then press "ok" button, the value will be shown in my select option
The problem is when I open the modal again and check the categories again with the same value/name, the value will be shown twice in my select option. So, I will get double category with the same value/name.. How to avoid this?

This is my addCategory page(modal)

```
<div class="right_col" role="main">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="x_panel">
        <div class="x_content">                    
          <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkAllCategory">Kategori
                  </th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxCategory[]" categoryID="{{$category->id}}" title="{{$category->CategoryName}}" class="checkboxCategory">
                        <a href="{{route('category.edit', $category->id)}}">{{ $category->CategoryName }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="center">
                      <a href="#" categoryID="{{$category->id}}" title="{{$category->CategoryName}}" class="chooseCategory">Pilih</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my select option

```
<span>Kategori yang diizinkan untuk post</span>
      <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="IsAllCategory" value="1" id="IsAllCategory">
        <label for="IsAllCategory">Semua Kategori</label>
      </p>
      <div id="AllowedCatContent"> 
        <select multiple="" id="AllowedCategories" name="AllowedPostCategories[]" style="width: 500px; height: 200px; float: left"> 
        </select> 
        <a href="#" class="addKategori ui btn btn-default" style="margin: 3px 4px;">Tambah kategori</a>
        <br> 
        <a href="#" class="deleteUrl ui btn btn-danger" style="margin: 3px 4px;">Hapus</a> 
      </div>
```

and this is my jquery

```
$('.addKategori').click(function(){
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
var modal = $('#mymodal').modal();
modal.find('.modal-title').html('Tambah kategori');
modal.find('.modal-body').html('<p>Loading&hellip;</p>');
modal.find('.modal-body').load('{{route("role.add.category")}}',{},function(){

  modal.find('.ok').unbind().click(function(){
    modal.find('.checkboxCategory:checked').each(function(){
      $('#AllowedCategories').append('<option value="'+$(this).attr('categoryID')+'">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</option>');
    });
    modal.modal('hide');
  });

  $('.chooseCategory',modal).click(function(){
    $('#AllowedCategories').append('<option value="'+$(this).attr('categoryID')+'">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</option>');
    modal.modal('hide');
    return false;
  });



});
return false;});

$('.checkAllCategory').click(function(){
var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
$(this).parents('.dataTables_scrollHead').next().children().find('[name^="checkboxCategory"]').prop('checked', checked);});



$('#AllowedCategories option').each(function(){
if($(this.selected)){
    var selectID = $(this).val();
    $('.checkboxCategory').each(function(){
        var checkID = $(this).attr('categoryID');
        if(selectID == checkID){
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to clear the select before re-append it back. 
Try add `$('#AllowedCategories').html('');` in your button ok click and before re-append the list.

```
 $('#AllowedCategories').empty();
    modal.find('.checkboxCategory:checked').each(function(){
              $('#AllowedCategories').append('<option value="'+$(this).attr('categoryID')+'">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</option>');
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just check does it exists before append value. Just simple

```
modal.find('.ok').unbind().click(function(){
modal.find('.checkboxCategory:checked').each(function(){

    if($('#AllowedCategories option[value="'+$(this).attr('categoryID')+'"]').length == 0)
        $('#AllowedCategories').append('<option value="'+$(this).attr('categoryID')+'">'+$(this).attr('title')+'</option>');
});

modal.modal('hide');
```

});

You can also clear selectbox before adding, but check before add like this will keep current selected index

Comment: sorry, I forgot about it.. Your code is work, thankyou for your feedback. I appreciate it!